# Count rows in a join against another table

Tags: mysql, sql

Product Table columns:

- image1
- product_type
- product.amount
- price
- description
- product_id

Offers Table columns:

- Offer_id
- Product_id
- Offered person

I need to get count of `offer_id` by using `product_id` on these two tables. I also need to get product list my filtering by `product_type`.

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(offers_id) AS offers,
       image1,
       product_type,
       product.amount,
       product.price,
       description,
       product.product_id
FROM product INNER JOIN offers ON product.product_id = offers.product_id
WHERE product_type LIKE '%$product_type%'"
```

But this query returns only one product from the product table.

Comment: This may be a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464564/join-two-tables-mysql-one-to-many-relationship

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a count of grouped information you have to use GROUP BY, e.g:

```
SELECT COUNT(offers_id) AS offers, image1, product_type, product.amount, product.price, description, product.product_id  
FROM product INNER JOIN offers ON product.product_id = offers.product_id  
WHERE product_type LIKE '%$product_type%'"
GROUP BY image1, product_type, product.amount, product.price, description, product.product_id
```